# При изменении одного списка в словаре, меняются остальные списки в этом словаре

Tags: python, словари

Почему при изменении одного из списков в словаре, созданном этой функцией, меняются и все остальные списки этого словаря?

```
def create_dict(rounds):
    cur_dict = {}
    s = requests.session()
    r = s.get('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker')
    data = r.json()
    roundlist = []
    while len(roundlist)<rounds:
        roundlist.append(0)
    for k in sorted(data.keys()):
        if k.startswith('BTC'):
            cur_dict.update({k:roundlist})
    return cur_dict
```

Comment: Всё что относится к вопросу, должно содержаться в самом вопросе, а не по ссылкам.

Comment: Поясните, что вы подразумеваете под "дублирует значения в словаре".

Comment: for на 47 строчке должен передать значение из data[key['last'] в i столбец(i элемент списка) словаря cur_dict с ключем key. А передает по всем ключам. Весь 'столбец' в итоге становится с одним значение.

Comment: @Snez_ok, перенесите весь необходимый код непосредственно в вопрос. Если кода много, то необходимо изолировать проблему и написать [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В функции create_dict у вас есть такой код:

```
roundlist = []
while len(roundlist)<rounds:
    roundlist.append(0)
for k in sorted(data.keys()):
    if k.startswith('BTC'):
        cur_dict.update({k:roundlist})
```

То есть, вы создаёте один список и назначаете его каждому ключу в словаре.

Здесь необходимо понимать, что хотя вы таким образом прописали в словаре его множество раз, это всё равно остаётся один и тот же список.

Естественно, когда вы меняете его через один из ключей, он сразу же изменяется по всем остальным ключам. Просто потому, что на самом деле это один и тот же список.

Чтобы всё заработало, вам нужно переписать функцию так:

```
def create_dict(rounds):
    cur_dict = {}
    s = requests.session()
    r = s.get('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker')
    data = r.json()
    for k in sorted(data.keys()):
        if k.startswith('BTC'):
            cur_dict.update({k: [0 for _ in range(rounds)]})
    return cur_dict
```

Этот код будет создавать действительно отдельный список для каждого ключа.

PS: Когда будете задавать ещё вопросы на stackoverflow, соблюдайте требования к оформлению вопросов.

PPS: Кстати, я так и не понял, зачем вы сортируете ключи словаря, прежде чем итерироваться по ним. В этом есть какой-то сакральный смысл?

Comment: Иногда не хватает опыта адекватно локализовать проблемный кусок.
Замечания по оформлению и сортировке принял, спасибо.

Comment: @Snez_ok ответ исправил одну ошибку, но в коде могут быть и другие. Стилистические замечания: 1- излишне писать data.keys() (а на Питоне 2 это ещё дополнительно было бы не эффективно), можно просто data¶ 2- вместо `[0 for _ in range(rounds)]` можно писать `[0] * rounds` (числа неизменяемы в Питоне, поэтому проблемы с использованием одного и того же объекта, чтобы представить ноль, нет)¶ 3- вместо `d.update({k:expr})` лучше писать `d[k] = expr`¶ 4- это делает очевидным, что sorted() бесполезно в коде. Цикл можно записать как: `return {k: [0]*rounds for k in r.json() if k.startswith('BTC')}`...

Comment: @Snez_ok ...[продолжение] можете задать вопрос с меткой  [tag:инспекция-кода], если хотите получить подобный отклик о рабочем коде.

Comment: Благодарю, jfs.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>это комментарий, опубликованный в виде ответа, чтобы код показать</sup>

В целом, код в вопросе можно упростить:

```
def create_dict(url, rounds):
    return {k: [0] * rounds
            for k in requests.get(url).json()
            if k.startswith('BTC')}
```

`create_dict` это слишком общее имя. Попробуйте более специфичное для вашей задачи имя для созданного объекта придумать, к примеру, `get_foombulator(url, rounds)`.